# How to resize a mdadm RAID array

Tags: boot, partitioning, raid, mdadm

My NAS is booted from a USB key that I have installed Linux Mint 18.2

The NAS contains a RAID 1 array (created using mdadm).

I want to move the swap from the USB key to the Raid array (the USB key is running out of space and I risk wearing out the USB stick), but I need to free some space on the RAID array.

I've tried unmounting the array to follow the steps here: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-resize-raid-partitions-shrink-and-grow-software-raid
so I can then use resize2fs.

However when I unmount the "target is busy" and lsof and fuser don't give any useful processes that have the array in use (I killed samba for good measure).

Should I boot the NAS off a Live USB and then use gparted to resize the RAID array?  (and format the free space as swap)

Will I need to do anything when I boot from the original USB?, or can I proceed to configuring the Mint install to use the new swap partition on the NAS?

Comment: Please look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/76445/resizing-partitions-on-a-raid-0-array-by-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot unmount a partition wich has open files. The usual way to do this is to boot in [single user mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), or using a live system like you mentioned.

Then you can proceed with enlarging the partition and raid array, and the instructions you link seems to cover that quite well.

Note that you obviosly need free space on the drives to follow that procedure. To add drives, the process is [slightly different](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing).

Also note that a file server should run very well without swap. Swap is not used for caching, and the amount of swappable software on a NAS will be low. A box I have for storage has 2GiB RAM, and has swapped 86MiB - while using 700MiB of RAM for caching. Removing the swap totally would have negligible performance impact.

To disable the old swap space, edit /etc/fstab. You'll typically find a line like this:

```
/path/to/swap   none    swap    sw    0   0
```

Simply edit that line to point to the location of your new swap file, and ubuntu will use the new one on next boot. This can safely be edited before doing anything more, as Linux will run happily without swap.

Comment: Excellent - thanks - I did end up disabling swap completely and reclaiming the space.  However the swap was a bit stubborn to delete by just editing /etc/fstab, so I had to follow the correct answer listed here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224156/how-to-safely-turn-off-swap-permanently-and-reclaim-the-space-on-debian-jessie
THANKS!